# Spring-boot service listen ActiveMQ without app server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service, activemq-classic

There is an application on spring-boot. Listens to the ActiveQM queue and puts the data into the database through spring-data using spring-boot-starter-activemq / data-jpa. Now that it does not fall after launch, everything turns on spring-boot-starter-web-services. Are there any options in the background without tomcat which occupies the port? I don't need use http in this module

without spring-boot-starter-web-services application stop after lunche

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.in.name}")
        public void receiveMessageFromTopic(final ActiveMQMessage message) {
    ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your code so I can only guess what's happening. If your application stops it means there is no active (non-daemon) thread. Tomcat (included into spring-boot-starter-web-services) has at least one such thread.

I believe it will be enough to add bean which starts new Thread and parks it for infinite time (or some other event). You might want to add some logic for graceful shutdown in this case you need to unpark this thread.

Comment: I was hoping there was a more lightweight solution than tomcat